# Resize UILabel dynamically and reposition UIViews below it using Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, uilabel, xib

I have a `UILabel` that can contain any number of lines with a constrained width.  I have no problem resizing a `UILabel` to fit the given text, however, I am implementing a 'View More...'/'View Less...' button, which will either increase or decrease the size of the `UILabel`.  Based on this, any `UIView's` below this `UILabel` will be affected, and will need to be repositioned on their y-axis accordingly.

I am trying to use the built-in features within the XIB files and am having no luck at all.

**Autosizing settings for the UILabel:**

[image: Autosizing for UILabel]

**Autosizing for all UIViews below the UILabel:**

[image]

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here?  So essentially a scenario would be:

1. Screen loads
2. Label is populated with a certain amount of the available text with constrained width
3. `UIView's` below `UILabel` are repositioned as the `UILabel` has increased in height from the one displayed within XIB file
4. User presses 'View More' and the `UILabel` is resized to fit all the available text and increases in height and all UIView's are repositioned further down the screen accordingly
5. User presses 'View Less' and the `UILabel` decreases in height, hiding more text and `UIView's` move back up accordingly.

Thanks, hope this is explained clearly! I'm attempting to do as much in the XIB file as possible to reduce code, but all my UI elements are still accessible via `IBOutlets` if that proves to be the only solution *(I hope not)*.

**Note:** I am required to support iOS4.3 and above, so am unable to use iOS6 auto-layout functionality.

Comment: This could be done with only the code necessary to expand and contract the label if you use auto layout. Do you have a reason for not using that?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question? The label is expanded and contracted by adjusting the height of it whilst it is constrained to a particular width, this event occurs when the 'View more/View less' button is pressed

Comment: My question is about auto layout. Why are you using struts and springs instead of auto layout (which is turned on by default in iOS 6). Do you need to support OS's earlier than iOS 6?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood.  Supporting 4.3+ so cannot use autolayout features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to use the autosizing features in the end, so I resolved the issue by creating a UIView that acted as a container for all the subviews that were BELOW the UILabel that expanded.

I was then able to create a helper method that animated the frame adjusting according to the difference between the full size UILabel and the half sized label.

```
- (void)repositionMoveableViewContainerWithFrame:(CGRect)newFrame animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect newContainerPosition = self.moveableViewsContainer.frame;
    CGFloat difference = (newFrame.size.height - self.adjustableLabel.frame.size.height);
    newContainerPosition.origin.y = newContainerPosition.origin.y + difference;

    if (animated) {
        // Adjust frame animated
    } else {
        // Adjust frame without animation.
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Autoresizing usually only enforces subview layout when you alter the size of the parent view. You can link most of it up through IBOutlets, however, when you tap the view more button you will have to tell your parent view to resize.

If you are willing to, you could use these extensions on UIView: http://glassofcocoa.com/blog/2012/11/14/uiview-extensions/ and you could do it manually quite easily and with an animations - would look something like:

```
//assume you have a BOOL value wether toggled or not called 'isViewingMore' and a stored startHeight
- (IBAction)didTapViewMore:(id)sender
{
    if (!_isViewingMore)
    {
        _isViewingMore = YES;
        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(_myLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
        CGFloat lblheight = [@"" sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
        _myLabel.height = lblHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        _isViewingMore = NO;
        myView.height = startHeight
    }
    UIView *lastView = nil;
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ((id)view != (id)_myLabel)
        {
            if (lastView == nil)
            {
                view.top = _myLabel.bottom;
            }
            else
            {
                view.top = lastView.bottom;
            }
            lastView = view;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to take the IB only route, you will need to put your subviews in one parent view and resize the parent view - this should tell the children to update their positioning/size.

Hope this helps.